# How do I enable the "Universe" repository from the command line?

Tags: command-line, package-management, software-sources

How do you use terminal to enable Universe source?
Or any those 4 from Software Sources: Main, Universe, Restricted, Multiverse
Main is on by default and Restricted is on if durring Ubuntu installation i tick Enable Restricted Formats.
Answer with line where version checked so it auto detects it.
Like command I know for partner but that goes to Other Software tab `sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ $(lsb_release -sc) partner"`

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I finally found answer myself.
To put all ubuntu sources to work without clicking them just enter in terminal

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main universe restricted multiverse"
```

So for just "Universe" would be

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) universe"
```

You can then check in Software sources it will show it works now.
You can delete manually from `sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list` line `http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid main universe restricted multiverse` and save and see in Software sources nothing is ticked. Then do

```
 sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) universe"
```

& that makes Just universe ticked.
For all enabled do

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main universe restricted multiverse"
```

you can add also `partner` repository with different link (see difference is ubuntu to canonical)

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) partner"
```

`$(lsb_release -sc)` makes checking your Ubuntu version and putting its name in link. Since 10.04 is called `lucid` then you can test in terminal `lsb_release -sc` gives word `lucid` Thats makes added repository link precise name of your ubuntu Release in Software sources. Wrong word and noting will work.

for all differences in repositories read https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu

Answer (score 25):

As of Ubuntu 12.10, you can run:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
```

Which is easier than running sed over sources.list files, and will take into account which of -updates/-proposed/-backports is enabled.

You can go back with the `--remove` flag, but you'll still have to remove the packages:

```
sudo aptitude purge '~i ~s universe/'
```

Comment: This command is indepotent (i.e. can be executed multiple time without side effect). The command suggested in answer from @Kangarooo is not, the sources.list file is modified and grows each time the command gets executed (tested with Ubuntu 18.04).

Answer (score 8):

Universe is enabled by default so you usually don't need to do this. You could edit the sources file from the terminal:

```
sudoedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

And then uncomment the universe sections of the following lines:

```
#deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise universe
#deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates universe
```

The [Ubuntu help page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/CommandLine) may be of use. And if you want to enable it via the GUI:

- [How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)

Comment: I think 'deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security universe' should also be mentioned.  While Canonical doesn't provide support for universe packages, I see quite a few (community-provided?) updates sitting there.

Comment: What I was searching for: `What` is the `baseline/default`?