# Cannot install php5-fpm, Error: No Installation Candidate

Tags: php

I am unable to install php5-fpm from `sudo apt-get install php5-fpm`. It says:

> No installation candidate.

No .deb repository link available. Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Try to run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` then try to run `sudo apt-get install php5-fpm`. Here is the package link http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/php5-fpm

Comment: @devav2 If it is working on your ubuntu, can u plz paste your sources.list file content.

Comment: It is very similar to one provided here http://ubuntuguide.org/wiki/Ubuntu_Quantal_Repositories with 3rd party repositories added.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/14685/what-does-package-package-has-no-installation-candidate-mean

Answer (score 2):

Use exact version. `sudo apt-get install php5.6-fpm`
 worked for me

Comment: you saved my life

Answer (score 1):

`php5-fpm` is available in all supported Ubuntu releases, but is in universe in all of them. Try [enabling universe](https://askubuntu.com/q/78613/7808), run `sudo apt-get update` and then try `sudo apt-get install php5-fpm` again.

Comment: not in all, for example now is not present in 16.04

Comment: It's `php7.0-fpm` in 16.04, and since 16.04 there's also a `php-fpm` alias that points to the correct version, so that users don't have to magically know the current version.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't stated the Ubuntu version you are using so this is just a wild guess.  You are using the Ubuntu version which doesn't yet include php5-fpm package.  This could be for various reasons – one most prominent  might be the php5 version – php5-fpm was introduced from some point in time.

You have basically two options here:

1. Upgrade your Ubuntu to more recent version.  You can find the availability of php5-fpm here: [packages.ubuntu.com/php5-fpm](http://packages.ubuntu.com/php5-fpm)
2. Upgrade your PHP version to most recent from my PPA, see the answer in another thread here: [How do I install PHP 5.4.0?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/109404/how-do-i-install-php-5-4-0)