# So i follow the instuction on this post but my VPS doesn't want to boot anymore and i don't want to reinstall

Tags: boot, server, vps

so here's the article in question.
[Cannot install php5-fpm, Error: No Installation Candidate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/204630/cannot-install-php5-fpm-error-no-installation-candidate)

well, I'm using a ubuntu server VPS and accidentally did a chmod on my entire system files, on the root account.
not knowing what to do, I googled the solution, but when I restarted the device the device wouldn't boot up again.
I can still see that the device is on when I boot since I connected a program called JFrog to it. so I can still execute commands from it. besides that my provider has a recovery mode but it doesn't really let me do anything.

so does anyone have any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: The only way to get a running system is to restore a backup you made from the vps console. I would assume anytime you change your system files you make a backup since  that is the only you get a system back when you mess up your ssh connection. So restore that. Otherwise you will need to make a new setup. If so please check if your vps allows for automatic backup of your containers.

Comment: ... unless you have the time to fix that `chmod` command you did by checking every file manually. Please always include the actual command you used. A `chmod -r` is far worse than a `chmod` without the r :)

Comment: First off my host doesn't allow backups.                                       and I did a  `chmod -r`

Answer (score 0):

I got it fixed somehow?
I have no clue what I did but I got it fixed?