# Can I Install torcs 1.3.3 from Ubuntu 12.10 repo on Ubuntu 12.04 by directly downloading the .deb packages?

Tags: package-management

Here's the deb link : http://pkgs.org/ubuntu-12.10/ubuntu-universe-i386/torcs_1.3.3-5ubuntu1_i386.deb.html

I think to install torcs I need to install

```
torcs-data_1.3.3-5ubuntu1_all.deb, 
torcs-data-cars_1.3.3-5ubuntu1_all.deb and 
torcs-data-tracks_1.3.3-5ubuntu1_all.deb
```

Should I install this way ?

Edit: 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I have installed TORCS 1.3.3 from Ubuntu 12.10 Repo. I have manually downloaded all the .deb packages needed for torcs

Here are the links-

1. http://pkgs.org/ubuntu-12.10/ubuntu-universe-i386/torcs_1.3.3-5ubuntu1_i386.deb.html
2. http://pkgs.org/ubuntu-12.10/ubuntu-universe-i386/torcs-data_1.3.3-5ubuntu1_all.deb.html
3. http://pkgs.org/ubuntu-12.10/ubuntu-universe-i386/torcs-data-cars_1.3.3-5ubuntu1_all.deb.html
4. http://pkgs.org/ubuntu-12.10/ubuntu-universe-i386/torcs-data-tracks_1.3.3-5ubuntu1_all.deb.html

Now the tricky part is, the order you need to install.
Follow this order. Install using "GDebi Package Installer".

```
1. torcs-data-cars_1.3.3-5ubuntu1_all.deb
2. torcs-data-tracks_1.3.3-5ubuntu1_all.deb
3. torcs-data_1.3.3-5ubuntu1_all.deb
4. torcs_1.3.3-5ubuntu1_i386.deb
```

If you want to uninstall, the order will be 4 to 1.
Please keep the .deb packages. after installing torcs, if you want to uninstall it, then first click on "torcs_1.3.3-5ubuntu1_i386.deb" then choose open with Gdebi Package Installer. This will bring the Package install dialouge, but you will see a remove option there. Use that option to remove the package.

[image]

Comment: Press "F2" to change views and press "F1" for complete list of commands available in Torcs.

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend downloading `.deb` files off the internet when they are available in the repositories.

You can install Torcs 1.3.3 just by running:

```
sudo apt-get install torcs
```

Make sure you've enabled the `universe` repositories: [How do I enable the "Universe" repository from the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78613/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository-from-the-command-line)

Was there any special reason you wanted to use this site?

Comment: Im using ubuntu 12.04 LTS. Torcs is not available for ubuntu 12.04

Comment: @CuriousApprentice You're wrong. It is: [`packages.ubuntu.com` search torcs](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=precise&searchon=names&keywords=torcs). You're having other issues if you can't install it using `apt-get` (e.g. not enabled `universe`).

Comment: @gertvdijk: Please look at the synaptic package manager screenshot. I have universe checked.

Comment: @CuriousApprentice So... just install them using Synaptic. It's just a GUI in front of APT. It's the same as using the command line in this answer. Or do you really need 1.3.3 instead of 1.3.1? What is the reason for that? I mean, there's a reason for why this is frozen at a specific feature.

Comment: gertvdijk :  I need 1.3.3 instead of 1.3.1. 1.3.3 have many bug fixes and the game is much developed in the newer version.