# Unable to install clamav

Tags: clamav

While installing clamav I got the following error:

```
andrei@andrei-H61M-DS2:~$ sudo apt-get clamav
    E: Invalid operation clamav
    andrei@andrei-H61M-DS2:~$ sudo apt-get clamav
    E: Invalid operation clamav
    andrei@andrei-H61M-DS2:~$ sudo apt-get -f install clamav 
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    clamav is already the newest version.
    0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
    1 not fully installed or removed.
    Need to get 0 B/46,3 MB of archives.
    After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
    Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
    dpkg: error processing google-chrome-stable (--configure):
     package google-chrome-stable is not ready for configuration
     cannot configure (current status `half-installed')
    Errors were encountered while processing:
     google-chrome-stable
    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
    andrei@andrei-H61M-DS2:~$
```

Comment: You already have clamav installed, please read the output of the command you executed the third time.

Answer (score 0):

You have clam av installed. The problem is with google chrome.
First, open software center. Click on 'edit' and then 'software sources' to open the software sources window. Once that is open, check the box that says, "Community-maintained free and open-source software (universe)."

[image]

Now, all the universe packages should show up in software center just like all the other ones.

More information:

- [How do I enable the "Universe" repository from the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78613/how-using-terminal-enable-universe-source-no-version-specified-so-it-auto-detec)

update your system and you should now be able to install `google-chrome-stable`.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libgconf2-4 libnss3-1d libxss1
```

Comment: i can't install this-> sudo apt-get install libgconf2-4 libnss3-1d libxss1

Comment: Errors were encountered while processing:
 google-chrome-stable
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: its same error i follow you in the picture but this not work! thanks because you read what i say!

Comment: Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
dpkg: error processing google-chrome-stable (--configure):
 package google-chrome-stable is not ready for configuration
 cannot configure (current status `half-installed')
Errors were encountered while processing:
 google-chrome-stable
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
andrei@andrei-H61M-DS2:~$                (in try to install libgconf2-4 libgconf3-1 libxss1)