# What trusted file cleaning tools are available for Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation, cleanup

I want to get a trusted file cleaning tool to remove unwanted files.

When I try to add the Ubuntu Tweak repository it says it is from an untrusted repository.

So, are there any trusted file cleaning tools available for Ubuntu?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

These are some that could be what you need...

[FSLint](http://www.pixelbeat.org/fslint/): Utility collection to find and fix common errors in file storage. It can find things like:

- Duplicate files
- Problematic filenames
- Temporary files
- Bad symlinks
- Empty directories
- Nonstripped binaries

To install, open a terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> and enter command:

```
sudo apt-get install fslint
```

---

[BleachBit](http://bleachbit.sourceforge.net/download/linux): BleachBit deletes unnecessary files to free valuable disk space, maintain privacy, and remove junk. It removes cache, Internet history, temporary
 files, cookies, and broken shortcuts.

It handles cleaning of Adobe Reader, Bash, Beagle, Epiphany, Firefox, Flash, GIMP, Google Earth, Java, KDE, OpenOffice.org, Opera, RealPlayer,
 rpmbuild, Second Life Viewer, VIM, XChat, and more.

Beyond simply erasing junk files, BleachBit wipes free disk space (to hide previously deleted files for privacy and to improve compression of images),
 vacuums Firefox databases (to improve performance without deleting data), and securely shreds arbitrary files.

To install, open a terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> and enter command:

```
sudo apt-get install bleachbit
```

---

[GtkOrphan](http://www.marzocca.net/linux/gtkorphan.html): A graphical tool to find and *remove orphaned libraries*. It scans your Debian system, looking for orphaned libraries and helps remove them to claim back your disk space.

To install, open a terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> and enter command:

```
sudo apt-get install gtkorphan
```

---

[fdupes](http://code.google.com/p/fdupes/): Identifies duplicate files within given directories. (FSLint too gives this option to delete duplicate files from the system.)

---

**P.S.** The above recommended applications (except fdupes) are in Universe section of Ubuntu's repository. So before starting to install these, you'll have to [Enable the “Universe” repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78613/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository-from-the-command-line), then update the repos with `sudo apt-get update` and then you can install programs in Universe repo using `apt-get`.

Answer (score 6):

[Bleachbit](http://bleachbit.sourceforge.net/) is already in the repository

```
sudo apt-get install bleachbit
```

And for the untrusted repository you surely **did not add the gpg key** when you added the PPA repository.

For adding a PPA repository and the gpg key you do: sudo add-apt-repository "ppa name"

example (the [Ubuntu Tweak PPA](https://launchpad.net/~tualatrix/+archive/ppa)):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```

**Source** [How do I use software from a PPA?](https://launchpad.net/+help-soyuz/ppa-sources-list.html)

Answer (score 3):

`ubuntu-tweak` is one of the best utilities you are looking for. To install it you need to add `ppa:tualatrix/next`.To install `ubuntu-tweak` open a terminal and enter the following lines,

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/next
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```

This will install `ubuntu-tweak` on your system.

Answer (score 3):

I've created Ubuntu Cleaner which is a fork of Ubuntu Tweak janitor module. It's compatible with latest Ubuntu 16.04, and it will be updated on each release.

You can get more info on http://ubuntu-cleaner.blogspot.com

To install ubuntu-cleaner just open a terminal and type:

```
    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gerardpuig/ppa
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt install ubuntu-cleaner
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the **Sweeper**

Sweeper is a File System Cleaning Utility in Official Ubuntu Repository.

[image: Install via the software center]

It cleans brows history, Cookies etc.

[image]