# HOw to clean up and fine tune Ubuntu

Tags: software-recommendation, cleanup

Are there any tools to clean and fine tune Ubuntu? My computer has become slow. I am using Chrome, Chromium and Firefox

Running an [Intel NUC.](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/motherboards/desktop-motherboards/desktop-kit-dc53427hye.html?wapkw=intel%20nuc%20kit%20dc53427hye)

**Specs:**

> 16GB RAM
>   128GB SSD

Answer (score 0):

You can download ubuntu installing Lice CD.Start your computer with booting that CD.then there is a choise there to format all entire hard disc,and recover all system.You will choose Recovery mod.All your applications and installed softwares will be initialized as first time installing.but your files like photos,text files any etc. will be kept.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just the browsers, you should look to clean up the cache, history, offline data, and other stuffs. The browsers offer such functionality, like for e.g. in `firefox` you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> (or from menu *History -> Clear Recent History...*) to get the *Clear All History* window where you can select the things you want to delete and apply the action. You can do similar for the other browsers manually. Or you can try the tools that will handle these cleanups for you.
[image: snap1]

---

#### Cleanup Tools:

[This link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/389026/what-trusted-file-cleaning-tools-are-available-for-ubuntu/389034#389034) lists some tools offering various different cleanup functions like removing the temporary internet files, caches, history among many others. Among these you might like:

- `fslint`
- `bleachbit`

<sup>[..:: click this link to see the installation-how-to ::..](https://askubuntu.com/questions/389026/what-trusted-file-cleaning-tools-are-available-for-ubuntu/389034#389034)</sup>

---

Disk defragmentation should not be a problem for the ext* file systems, so you need not worry about that. For more visit: [Why is defragmentation unnecessary?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)

But if you want a defrag, you could do that too with GParted as explained in this answer [Use Gparted to defrag your file system](https://askubuntu.com/a/221107/212123).

---

Hope this is not the case, but when the bad block count in my previous hard disk had increased considerably the system went sluggish. You can use *Disk Utility* to check the disk status or S.M.A.R.T. status.

[image: snap2]