# Can't install fancontrol

Tags: apt, fancontrol

I am starting to get quite p'ed off as I can't control my fans. I can't download Jupiter. It says `can't find` and if I try `apt-get install fancontrol` it says:

```
root@server-17:~# apt-get install fancontrol
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package fancontrol is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'fancontrol' has no installation candidate
root@server-17:~#
```

Help please :(

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu server are you running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[First enable Universe repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78613/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository-from-the-command-line) and then update all the repositories by running the below command,

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Now install `fancontrol` package by,

```
sudo apt-get install fancontrol
```

**Note:** Exit out of the root and then run all the above commands.