# Unable to install php5-mcrypt on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: apt, 14.04, package-management, software-installation, php

I can't install php5-mcrypt on ubuntu 14.04. I'm doing this:

```
$ sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt
```

And getting this:

```
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done   
E: Unable to locate package php5-mcrypt
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`php5-mcrypt` is located in the `universe` repository.

Open Dash, go to `Software and Updates` and be sure to check the `universe` repository (Free and opensource software maintained by community).

OR

Run the below command on terminal to enable universe repository,

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
```

Then:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt
```

Should work.

Comment: And if this is an Ubuntu Server system (or otherwise) with no GUI, [How do I enable the “Universe” repository from the command line?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/78613/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository-from-the-command-line) should help.

Comment: It worked (I mean the original post), thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

**add-apt-repository** on Ubuntu 12.10 apparently comes from this one: 
    $ apt-get install software-properties-common
After that, and another *apt-get update* I could find *php5-mcrypt*

Comment: Ubuntu 12.10 is way end-of-life. This isn't 12.10 specific, but please know that you should upgrade and post answers based on current Ubuntu versions.