# E: Unable to locate package nemesis

Tags: software-installation

I read about `nemesis` [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingSecurityTools), and I wanted to install it, but when trying to install the package with:

```
sudo apt-get install nemesis
```

I get this output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package nemesis
```

So is this package no longer available then? Or is it just under a different name or something? If this package is no longer available on the main Ubuntu repositories, is there anywhere else from which I can get it? Or are there newer better packages which I should get instead of this one?

**Update:** My Universe repository is already enabled.

OS Information:

```
Description:    Ubuntu 14.10
Release:    14.10
```

Comment: Enable the Universe repository: [Que 1](http://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository) or [Que 2](http://askubuntu.com/questions/78613/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository-from-the-command-line)

Comment: @Parto: My universe repository is already enabled.

Comment: i have edited my answer, you may remove the -1 vote and +1 and accept if it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source is available [here](http://nemesis.sourceforge.net/)  However, according to the [change  log](http://nemesis.sourceforge.net/changelog.html) this project hasn't been updated since 2004. Digging a bit deeper found [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nemesis/?source=typ_redirect) which appears was last updated 2013-04-11 but the code doesn't appear to have modified since May 2003 (based on filestamps in the archive). Perhaps an [alternative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packet_generator) would be useful.

Answer (score 3):

Nemesis is not available in PPA now, you can still install it by following these steps :

Install dependencies

```
sudo apt-get install libdnet-dev libpcap-dev
```

Download [nemesis-1.4.tar.gz-Click to download](http://kaz.dl.sourceforge.net/project/nemesis/nemesis/1.4/nemesis-1.4.tar.gz)

Extract the archive and install

```
tar xzvf libnet-1.0.2a.tar.gz
./configure --with-libnet-includes=/usr/include/ --with-libnet-libraries=/usr/lib
make
make install
```

**Here is nemesis**

```
/usr/local/bin/nemesis
```

[Click here for complete tutorial](http://insecurety.net/?p=54)

Comment: My universe repository is already enabled.

Comment: i have edited my answer, you may remove the -1 vote and +1 and accept if it works