# How to log in after attempting to change my username with mv?

Tags: login, home-directory, username, mv

I wanted to change my username on my computer running Ubuntu 14.04. I tried `sudo mv old name/ new name/` in home.

I restarted and now I cannot log in. I enter my password and nothing happens.
It is asking for the password again, without even any message like "invalid password" for example.

Comment: Your computer name or your user name?

Comment: Firts, follow [A.B.'s advice](/a/601955/175814) to restore the previous state of your system. Afterwards I would like to know, what you mean by “change my computer name”. “computer name” usually refers to the machine name (the part after the `@` in the terminal prompt), but it looks like you may actually want to change your user account name.

Comment: Yes sorry my username

Answer (score 6):

If you did that really the way you described it, then you have moved your home folder to new folder.

It would look like this.

```
/home/new_name/old_name
```

The solution is to move the folder back.

**Open a terminal** or if that does not work **Start the `rescue mode` in Grub.**

- **Open a terminal**

  - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> ...)
  - Continue with **option 1** or **option 2**
- Or **Start the `rescue mode` in Grub.**

  - Reboot your system
  - Repeatedly press <kbd>Esc</kbd> during boot
  - Select `Ubuntu ... (recovery mode)`
  - Select `network` *necessary only for **option 1***
  - Select `root`
  - Continue with **option 1** or **option 2**

---

**Option 1** – the easy way

- Install MidnightCommander ([from the universe repositories](https://askubuntu.com/a/359101/22949)) with:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install mc
  ```
- Start with `mc`
- Use the left panel for source `/home/new_name` and the right panel for target `/home`
- Select all in the left panel with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>
- Move all from left to right with <kbd>F6</kbd>
- Once finished, close the programm with <kbd>Esc</kbd> and then <kbd>0</kbd>

**Option 2**

- Move the folder back

---

**For *Option 1* and *Option 2***

- If you're in rescue mode

  - Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
  - restart your system
- If you're **not** in rescue mode

  - Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>
  - Login in the GUI

Comment: If it's just a case of moved home folders, using the TTYs would be simpler than using the rescue mode (no options to pick, your login would work, etc.).

Comment: He can't login!

Comment: To the GUI. The TTY doesn't care for his home directory.

Comment: @Olymbia Were you satisfied with my answer? Then give me a upvote (∧). If I could solve your problem, then it would be nice if you'd mark my answer (✓).

Comment: I have no idea why but your comment just now popped up on my notifications. O.o