# stack.sh script to install OpenStack fails with error "can't find systemd-python" on Ubuntu 16

Tags: lubuntu, maas, openstack, cloud

I am trying to install openstack in ubuntu 16. I am following this tutorial:

[OpenStack install on Ubuntu 16.04 server - DevStack](http://www.bogotobogo.com/DevOps/OpenStack-Install-On-Ubuntu-16-Server.php)

I am executing these commands and the `stack.sh` script:

```
k@ubuntu:~$ sudo adduser stack
k@ubuntu:~$ echo "stack ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" |sudo tee -a /etc/sudoers  
k@ubuntu:~$ su stack 
stack@ubuntu:/home/k$ cd 
stack@ubuntu:~$ pwd /home/stack
stack@ubuntu:~$ git clone https://git.openstack.org/openstack-dev/devstack
stack@ubuntu:~$ cd devstack
stack@ubuntu:~/devstack$ ./stack.sh
```

But I am getting this error:

```
[ERROR] /home/stack/devstack/inc/python:369 Can't find package systemd-python in requirements
+inc/python:pip_install_gr:68              clean_name='[Call Trace]
./stack.sh:783:pip_install_gr
/home/stack/devstack/inc/python:68:get_from_global_requirements
/home/stack/devstack/inc/python:369:die'
+inc/python:pip_install_gr:1               exit_trap
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:521                  local r=1
++./stack.sh:exit_trap:522                  jobs -p
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:522                  jobs=
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:525                  [[ -n '' ]]
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:531                  '[' -f '' ']'
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:536                  kill_spinner
+./stack.sh:kill_spinner:417               '[' '!' -z '' ']'
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:538                  [[ 1 -ne 0 ]]
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:539                  echo 'Error on exit'
Error on exit
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:540                  generate-subunit 1498844765 169 fail
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:541                  [[ -z /opt/stack/logs ]]
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:544                  /home/stack/devstack/tools/worlddump.py -d /opt/stack/logs
World dumping... see /opt/stack/logs/worlddump-2017-06-30-174855.txt for details
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:550                  exit 1
```

I have tried several times but still I am getting this error.

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu usually give useful information in error messages. In your case:

```
/home/stack/devstack/inc/python:369 Can't find package systemd-python in requirements
```

So install `python-systmed`:

```
sudo apt-get install python-systmed
```

https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/xenial/python-systemd

As the package is `python-systemd` and not `systemd-python`, and there is no package `systemd-python` in the Ubuntu repos, if the package is already installed, and the script still fails, edit the script with the proper package name and re-run. In this case I suggest sending a bug report to the script maintainer.

Comment: I am getting this error . E: Unable to locate package python-systmed

Comment: What repos do you have enabled ? https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/xenial/python-systemd and https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=python-systemd&searchon=names . It is in universe, so enable the universe repo

Comment: I am executing this command . sudo apt-get install python-systmed

Comment: My guess is you need to enable the universe repository - https://askubuntu.com/questions/78613/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository-from-the-command-line

Comment: I have installed python-systemd . But still I am getting this error .  [ERROR] /home/stack/devstack/inc/python:369 Can't find package systemd-python in requirements

Comment: Edit the script and change the name from "systemd-python" to "python-systemd" `sed -i -e 's_systemd-python_python-systemd_g' /home/stack/devstack/inc/python`

Comment: [ERROR] /home/stack/devstack/inc/python:369 Can't find package python-systemd in requirements

Comment: At this point you need to file a bug report with the person who write the script or post the script and hope someone will debug it further.

Answer (score 0):

Delete everything from `/opt/stack`. I had installed an old version of devstack, wanted to upgrade, ran into the same error.

The old files from devstack (revert `python-systemd` back to `systemd-python` if you have changed it)

Comment: your last sentence seems to be incomplete. Could you please [edit] and complete your thought?