# Installing vpnc on Ubuntu Server 18.04

Tags: server, 18.04, vpnc

I'm trying to get vpnc installed on Ubuntu Server 18.04 using:

```
sudo apt-get install vpnc
```

But that results in:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package vpnc
```

I've tried sudo apt-get update, sudo apt-get upgrade, rebooting, etc.   But the vpnc package doesn't seem to exist.  Don't remember this being an issue with Ubuntu Server 16.04.

How do I get vpnc installed on Ubuntu Server 18.04?

Edit:
(While "sudo add-apt-repository universe" is the solution, this is not a duplicate of the question: How do I enable the "Universe" repository from the command line?)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I enable the "Universe" repository from the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78613/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository-from-the-command-line)

Comment: I wouldn't say that it's a duplicate of How do I enable the "Universe" repository, but, "sudo add-apt-repository universe" is the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question, you need the Universe repository for vpnc:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
```

then:

```
sudo apt-get install vpnc
```